# Go to next Page in UIPageViewController

Tags: swift, swift3, xcode8, ios10

I have a button and I just want to go to the next page.

I have read in other threads people saying to just used this,

```
setViewControllers([UIVIewController], direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

I have tried this in the button on a child view. I see that the PageControl (the little dots) has the functionality I want but I can't seem to find how apple implemented this. I have been reading a lot of posts on stackOverflow but I am not quite grasping it.

I have a rootViewController that implements the dataSource and delegate.

Answer (score 7):

First get the `current view controller` and `next view controller` and then pass the next view controller in `setViewControllers` function

```
func moveToNextPage() {

    guard let currentViewController = self.viewControllers?.first else { return print("Failed to get current view controller") }

    guard let nextViewController = self.dataSource?.pageViewController( self, viewControllerAfter: currentViewController) else { return }

    setViewControllers([nextViewController], direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: nil)

}
```

I hope this helps you.